# POSTGRES - How to create a select query that would join two databases?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a problem with join 2 database.  First.. I tried use this query:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM my_db1.table1 tb1 
LEFT JOIN my_db2.table2 tb2 ON tb2.code = tb1.code
```

I get the following error:

> schema "my_db2" does not exist.

So I tried:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dblink('my_db2', 'SELECT * FROM table2')
```

But it still doesn't work.
What should I do, to select from two tables that are in different databases?

Answer (score 4):

This should work with [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/contrib-dblink-function.html) for two databases in the same cluster where the calling user has the necessary privileges to both. Call from a connection to your `db1`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1 tb1 
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT *
   FROM   dblink('dbname=db2','SELECT id, code FROM table2')
   AS     tb2(id int, code text);
   ) USING (code)
```

Two things were missing: the connection string and the column definition list.

However, I would encapsulate access to a foreign table in a view or table function. [I quote the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/contrib-dblink-function.html):

> A convenient way to use dblink with predetermined queries is to create
>   a view. This allows the column type information to be buried in the
>   view, instead of having to spell it out in every query.